Unable to add signature only once when replying to emails in a VSTO Add-In
I am working on a VSTO Add-In for Outlook where I need to add a signature to an email when it is ready for composition. Specifically, this should happen only once when the email is opened for replying or replying to all.
Problem:
The event is triggering multiple times instead of just once. For example, when I use the Inspectors.NewInspector and CurrentExplorer.SelectionChange events, they are firing in situations where they shouldn’t, such as for inline responses or for new inspectors unrelated to replying.
Here’s my current implementation:
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    outlookApp = this.Application;
    inspectors = outlookApp.Inspectors;
    inspectors.NewInspector += Inspectors_NewInspector;

    // Hook to ActiveExplorer for inline responses
    currentExplorer = outlookApp.ActiveExplorer();
    if (currentExplorer != null)
    {
        currentExplorer.SelectionChange += CurrentExplorer_SelectionChange;
    }
}

private void Inspectors_NewInspector(Outlook.Inspector inspector)
{
    try
    {
        if (inspector.CurrentItem is Outlook.MailItem mailItem)
        {
            // Cast the inspector to the event interface
            Outlook.InspectorEvents_10_Event inspectorEvents = (Outlook.InspectorEvents_10_Event)inspector;

            // Subscribe to the Activate event
            inspectorEvents.Activate += () => Inspector_Activate(inspector, inspectorEvents);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show($"Error: {ex.Message}");
    }
}

private void CurrentExplorer_SelectionChange()
{
    try
    {
        // Check if there is an inline response
        var inlineResponse = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveExplorer().ActiveInlineResponse;
        if (inlineResponse != null && inlineResponse is Outlook.MailItem mailItem)
        {
            if (IsReplyEmail(inlineResponse))
            {
                // Adding signature
            }
        }
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
    }
}

I want to:

Detect when a reply or reply-all email is ready for composing.
Add a signature to the email at that moment.
Ensure this happens only once per email composition.

How can I reliably track when a reply/reply-all email is ready for composition without triggering the event multiple times? Is there a better way to handle this in the VSTO Add-In framework?

Are you saying both events fire more often than expected? While SelectionChange might indeed fire too often, I have never seen NewInspector misbehaving.

@DmitryStreblechenko, I didn’t mean that, just want to understand is there any inbuilt function ready for compose email

Which built-in function? To add a signature? It is added automatically upon display if you do not modify the message body prior to that.
